# How to get the all properties of an ObservableArray in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

How can I get all the properties of an ObservableArray in kncouout js 
let us consider a ObservableArray in knockout js

```
var repotviewmodel = function()
{
 this.types = ko.observableArray([
      { Id: '', Type: 'All' }, 
      { Id: '0', Type: 'Big file' }, 
      { Id: '1', Type: 'File' }, 
      { Id: '2', Type: 'Business' }, 
      { Id: '3', Type: 'Social Media'}
 ]);
```

So I want the values like `Id`, `Type` in an array this a hard coded array but in my case the array returns from the server side data So how can I get all the properties of the array so that result will be like

```
    this.Items =  ko.observableArray('Id','Type','firstName'......)

        };
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the expecting result ?
Please post and input and an expecting output data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate thorough the object's properties:

```
var self = this;
var myObject = self.types()[0];
for (var property in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        self.items.push(property);
    }
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Y9ru/

Comment: Since KO version 2.3.0 you can use `ko.utils.objectForEach` the same way as `ko.utils.arrayForEach`. i.e: `ko.utils.objectForEach( myObj, function(prop, value) { });`